# C++ operator '==' cannot compare string[i] with another string. Compile error

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "abcdef";
    string x = "a";
    if (str[0] == x) {
        //do something...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and cannot compile.

"error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’} and ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string’})"

Comment: You can't compare a single char with a string like that, no.

Comment: You could do `str[0] == x[0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string` except for being a string also provides interface of being a container of `char`s. So when you use [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) you access and individual `char` from this container and you cannot compare a `char` with a string. If you want to have a single symbol string instead use [`std::string::substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) with length 1. Or if you want the symbol to compare with another one declare `x` as being a single `char` instead of string.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're comparing a char with a string

str[0] is actually a char

Just need to declare x as char...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "abcdef";
    char x = 'a';
    if (str[0] == x) {
        //do something...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking why your code doesn't compile.

If we look at your code line by line we can see that...

> ```
> string str = "abcdef";
> string x = "a";
> if (str[0] == x)
> ```

From line one above you declared a string `str` that stores the set of character encoding values of {a, b, c, d, e, f} either it be ASCII, UTF-X, etc.

On your second line you declare another string `x` that stores the set of character encoding values of {a} either it be ASCII, UTF-X, etc.

The problem of not compiling does not show up until the expression within the if statement.

The `LHS` of the expression you are using `std::string`'s `operator[]` to access the value at the index of its first location in memory. This returns a reference to a character at that indexed location. Then on the `RHS` of the expression you are comparing the `LHS` character reference against the `std::string` named `x`.

The issue here is that there is no conversion between `a reference to a char`  and `std::string` and that you have not defined your own `operator==()` that would do so.

The easiest fix is to change either the `LHS` to a `string` or the `RHS` to a `char`. There may also be available functions or algorithms within the `STL` that would do the comparison(s) for you. You can do an online search for that.

> You can refer to [cppreference:string:basic_string:operator_at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) for detailed information about `std::string`'s `operator[]`. And you can search their site for other functions, algorithms and string manipulators and other types of containers. It is probably one of the best resources out there for the `C/C++` `STL`.